# Why SocketTimeoutException makes my program freeze?

Tags: java, multithreading, freeze, executorservice, socket-timeout-exception

I give my program over than 600 links, stocked in an `ArrayList` to get the title of the webpage, using JSoup (among others). For every link (using a **for** loop), I create a new thread (using `thread.start()`) and pass the link through my program, I wait for my thread to finish (with `thread.join`) before launching a new thread (simultaneous execution would cause some problems, I did that to prevent an unexpected thread end to stop the execution for the other links).

The problem is that sometimes, JSoup throws a SocketTimeoutException (which I'm supposed to catch), which makes my program freeze. I don't know why the execution stops even surrounded with a `try/catch`.

Here's a piece of my code, maybe that could help you understand :

```
// In the method actionPerformed() of my JPanel

for(final String link : links)
{
    Thread t = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Analyzer.process(link);
        }
    };
    t.start();
    try 
    {
        t.join();
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And in my process :

```
// method process() of my Analyzer class
try 
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(lien).userAgent("Mozilla").timeout(5*10000).get(); 
    //                    ^ EXCEPTION THROWN HERE ! ^

    title = doc.title();
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    erreurs+="Erreur lors de la lecture du titre\n";
}
```

It's annoying because the process is veeery long, I let it run for the night, and find today that my program froze at the 54th link. ^^' Thank you in advance !

**EDIT - UPDATE**

SercanOzdemir suggested me to use ExecutorService, instead of creating threads and making start()-join(), so I tried :

```
ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
for(final String link : links)
{
    System.err.println("-- "+i+" --");              //DEBUG
    ex.execute(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try
                {
                    Analyzer.process(link);
                }
                catch( Exception e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
    });
    i++;                                            //DEBUG
    }
ex.shutdown();
```

But it prints only my debug links. Any idea of why it doesn't run my process ?

Comment: Q. What exactly is the point of starting a thread only to immediately `join()` it without doing anything else in between? A. None.

Comment: @EJP If I use only one thread to execute my process on the 600 links, the only one thread interruption would stop the entire process (I already got this problem), and if I don't execute each process one after the other, I've got other problem (with some files treatment especially). I understand what you think, but that was the only way I found to resolve the problem with my knowledge. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried this with jsoup but it is a simple way of creating threads to do a task and monitoring their status.

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Future future = null;
    for(final String link : links)
    {
        future = executorService.submit(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
               Analyzer.process(link);
            }
            catch( Exception e ){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

        while(future != null
                && !future.isDone()
                && !future.isCancelled())
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000); // Or do something else
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    executorService.shutdown();
```

The code in your updated question won't work because you are creating the service and instantly overwriting it without waiting for it to complete.

```
ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
for(final String link : links)
{
  System.err.println("-- "+i+" --");              //DEBUG
  ex.execute(new Runnable(){ //Here it is created
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try
            {
                Analyzer.process(link);
            }
            catch( Exception e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
});
i++;                                            //DEBUG
//a split second later this loop finishes and overwrites the service again
}
ex.shutdown();
```

Comment: That while loop is a rather ugly solution... Just call executerService.awaitTermination()

Comment: It is ugly sure but executerService.awaitTermination(); is only useful if he has nothing else do on the main thread. If its a UI based program he could be updating a status bar etc.

Comment: @Victor It works well with the whil loop, maybe it would be better to use `awaitTermination()`, however it has 2 parameters so the method takes : `executorService.awaitTermination(long, TimeUnit)`, so what should I better pass as parameters in my case ?

Comment: executorService.awaitTermination() is not a replacement for the while loop. The while loop is checking to see if that Runnable(); has completed. executorService.awaitTermination() tells the ExecutorService to not accept any more Runnables and to wait for running threads to exit.

Comment: @GregKing, OK, but in this case,the main thread was being put to sleep anyway.Regarding the await(): for instance (1000, TimeUnit.Miliseconds)``, (5, TimeUnit.Minutes)`, etc

Comment: The while loop is a bad practice as it allows you to process one link at a time...

Comment: @Victor Indeed, I can't interact with my Frame while the process is running, so I'll use await(). Is there a way where I could still interact with my Frame ?

Comment: @Victor I tried await(), but actually the "while" loop is what I needed, since it waits for the task to end before launching a new task, that's what I need in my program

Answer (score 1):

Opening a new thread for every link is a very bad option.

Consider to use [ExecutionService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) if you want a multi-thread program.

If we come to your problem, I would rather to change this program exactly like below, because you are catching an exception on join part and that does not guarantee your exception has been thrown on this part..

```
new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run(){
                try{
                    // your codes
                }
                catch( Exception e ){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }.run();
```

Comment: I didn't know the existence of ExecutionService. I don't know how it works though, but it seems very promising since I could interact with my JPanel, so I'd rather try to use this option. So I'd create a new executor service outside my for loop (`ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`) then in my loop I'd write : `ex.execute(new Runnable() { [...] });` and after my loop, closing with `ex.shutdown()`, is that correct ?

Comment: And add a ex.waitForTermination()`or some of the submitted tasks might not be run.

Comment: Also, if your worker implements Callable instead of Runnable you might return the resutl of the operation easily.

Comment: yes that's correct, if you want to make it work at background.